# Hide a column on a row group ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I need to hide only one column with a parameter (Y/N) on a row group. the column visibility is gray out. I cannot select it. I can only select row visibility setting. but this one hide the entire row. is there any chance to hide only one column in a row group depend on the parameter? thanks

I created a column group for this column but it did not work

edit: when I hide the column, the space still remaining

Comment: Generally hiding a column will leave the blank space which is a known issue with SSRS and has been for many years. If you share your report design, making sure you show row and column groups then there might be ways around it. If you select the tablix control from the top left selector, it will show the grouping brackets which will make it easier to analyse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue, technically I created a new table that has a new column, the old one dont have this column. depend on my parameter I hide the one of the table. so I dont have any blank space issue. i dont think we need to hide the column